# How do we write function for "wait for ajax" until the page loads and use the same function among other test methods?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried with different waits option but couldn't able to click the button, i feel ajax takes time to load the page. How could i create a funtion for wait for ajax and use it in other method wherever i needed it.

```
for (int row=1;row<shipmentCount;row=+1)
        {

            try{

            WebElement onOfSkuWE= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fba-core-workflow-shipment-summary-shipment']/tr["+row+"]/td[3]"));
            String noOfSku = onOfSkuWE.getText();
            int noOfSkuValue = Integer.parseInt(noOfSku);

            if(mskuType.equalsIgnoreCase("single"))
            {
            if(noOfSku.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                waitForAjaxRefresh(driver);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("..//button["+row+"][@name='Work on shipment']")).click();
                break;
            }
            }
```

I'm getting unable to locate exception on "driver.findElement(By.xpath("..//button["+row+"][@name='Work on shipment']")).click();" this line.

```
<tbody id="fba-core-workflow-shipment-summary-shipment">
<tr>
<td>                      FBA (11/7/16 7:25 PM) - 1              </td>
<td>FBA43WZTCC</td>
<td class="number total-line-items">1</td>
<td class="number total-quantity">1</td>
<td>
<td>
<button class="amznBtn btn-lg-pri-arrowr" onclick="window.location='#FBA43WZTCC/prepare'" style="width: 28ex;" type="button" name="Work on shipment">
<p class="action-links content-bottom">
<p class="action-links">
<p/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
</tbody>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, or what have you investigated so far

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait for your element to locate. It will wait till the condition or the maximum wait time provided before throwing the Exception.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,20); // pass time in seconds as much you need
WebElement myElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("your element's id")));
```

Comment: Yes having the line at top of the method but yet the same result "WebElement noOfShipment = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 100)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("fba-core-workflow-shipment-summary-shipment")));"

Answer (score 0):

This is Ruby but ...

Selenium is trying to complete actions (such as clicking a button or link) before verifying that the target element has rendered on the page. Selenium can be more patient, but you have to explicitly ask him to be.

For example, if you are testing something that makes an AJAX request, you can try something like this (in Ruby):

```
# timeout is in seconds
def wait_for_ajax(timeout=x)
 time_limit, interval = (Time.now + timeout), 0.5
 loop do
   break if @driver.execute_script "return jQuery.active == 0"
   sleep interval
   raise "Wait for AJAX timed out after waiting for #{timeout} seconds" if Time.now > time_limit
 end
end
```

To ensure your tests are fully comprehensive, always make Selenium waits for elements to load before running a task.

This is for AJAX requests, however if this is not specifically related to Ajax, you just have to use implicit selenium wait. check this link : http://elementalselenium.com/tips/47-waiting